# Програмное закрытие fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Кто то сталкивался с автозакрытием через `setInterval` или `setTimeout` fancybox в Virtuemart 3. Перепробовал много способов, реализовать не получилось. Если кто то знает как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста. Может не туда скрипт добавляю.

```
function exit_fancy() {
   $.fancybox.close();
}
setTimeout(exit_fancy, 3000); 

//еще был 

function exit_fancy() {
   parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
setTimeout(exit_fancy, 3000)
```

Comment: 'onComplete' : function() { 
window.setTimeout($.fancybox.close, 11000);
} - тоже пробовал

Comment: и это  afterLoad: function(){
  setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },1000);
  }

Comment: Первый вариант вполне себе работает ([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/5EV8r/850/)). Ищите ошибку в чём-то другом.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!